# Display Images In A Row With Text Directly Underneath

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a few images in a row and display text that is directly underneath them and centered this is for my college work. I have tried some code but could not get it to work.

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
      <img height="200px" style="display: block; margin-left: 100px; float: left;border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 100%; margin-top: 30px;" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
      <img height="200px" style="display: block; margin-left: 500px; float: left;border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 100%; margin-top: 30px;" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
      <img height="200px" style="display: block; margin-left: 500px; float: left;border: 2px solid white; border-radius: 100%; margin-top: 30px;" src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
      <h3>Test</h3>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you should close the `<p>`-tags

Comment: @TK I have just done this and nothing has changed

Comment: It wouldn't change you problem but your syntax was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would do so:

```css
.test a {
    margin-left: 10px; 
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto; 
}

.test a img {
    width: 100px;
    border:2px solid white; 
    border-radius: 50%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
            <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
            <h3>Test</h3>
        </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
                <h3>Test</h3>
            </a>
           
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com">
                    <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
                    <h3>Test</h3>
                </a>
</div>
```

Key points:

- Use HTML for markup. Use CSS for style. Separate them.
- The p tag is not necessary.
- To float the three block on one line you have to set 'float:left' to the `<a>` element not in the img.
- If we use a float based layout we have to [Clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) (because the floats' container doesn't want to stretch up to accomodate the floats). This is why I added 'overflow: auto' to the container named '.test'
- Last but not least, there are tons of method for lay-out things with CSS. I recommend watching [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I would upvote if you add `.test:after { content: ''; display: block; clear: both;}` or tell me why not to clear floats or use `display: inline-block;` and not float

Comment: I try to do my best

Answer (score 0):

First of all, close your `<p>` tags.

Then personally I would an `inline-block` to the `p` and remove the `margin-left` on the img.

```
.test {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  display: block; 
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid white; 
  border-radius: 100%; 
  margin-top: 30px; 
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You needed to two things:

1. HTML wrapping DIVs to be able to control your blocks.
2. Using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Please, try this fiddle which may meet your requirement:

```html
<style>
    div.test {
    width:auto;
    margin: auto;
    }
    
    div.block {
 
    float: left;

    }
    
    div.block a{
    display:inline-block; 
    margin-left: 50px;
    }
    
    
    div.block img {
    border: 2px solid white; 
    border-radius: 100%;
    width:150px;
    }
    
    h3 {
    text-align: center;
    }
    
</style>

<div class="test">
<div class='block'>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
<img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
<h3>Test</h3>
</a>
</div>
<div class='block'>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
<img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
<h3>Test</h3>
</a>
</div>
    <div class='block'>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com">
<img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12512240_1005566046198664_2775546349199755757_n.jpg?oh=a37edadd99a4631e165accf6bd193a9f&oe=58C8AD58">
<h3>Test</h3>
</a>
    </div>
</div>
```